# Individuell/Individual- and Generell/General- Phenomena

Tags: grammar, adjective, noun

Can a native German speaker kindly explain this horrible inconsequence in his language?

An adjective `generell` but a noun `die Generalprobe`

Another example...

An adjective `individuell` but a noun `die Individualkondition`

Not to mention...

An adjective `offiziell` but a noun `der Offizialverteidiger`

and of course

An adjective `speziell` but a noun `die Spezialabteilung`

and even one more...

An adjective `traditionell` and an existing adjective `traditional`. The last one is an example of a total inconsequence.

Why are not those nouns written like that: `die Generellprobe`, `die Individuellkondition`, `der Offiziellverteidiger` and `die Speziellabteilung`?

Comment: I don't see why this is a horrible inconsequence. "Generalprobe" is not derived from "generell" but both "General..." and "generell" share–of course–their origin in [Genus](http://www.canoo.net/wordformation/genus:N:N)

Comment: Sorry but there is no separate word `general` and `individual` in German, so could you please explain more your point.

Comment: The same is true for individuell and [Individual-](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Individualbegriff). They share a common root (Latin **individualis**) and have since diverged a bit. In this case, the noun is **Individuum**, which is directly derived from the Latin root.

Comment: Just looked at canoo.net "Fiktive Einträge sind Wörter, die es geben könnte, die man aber in der wirklichen Sprache nicht gebraucht." Just great, even more fun learning.

Comment: @Jagger They are words that have been introduced into German as scientific/scholarly Latin terms that have been later absorbed into the language. The Duden article I linked above indicates that the adjective used to be individual too, but got modified over time.

Comment: There is nothing logical about language. As Doug Larson famously put it: *If the English language made any sense, lackadaisical would have something to do with a shortage of flowers.*

Comment: @Em1 Is the existence of two forms `traditionell` and [`traditional`](http://canoo.net/inflection/traditional:A) as adjectives in German also not an inconsequence for you?

Answer (score 2):

Look at another example `real` vs. `reell` vs. `real-`. The difference in usage is totally inconsequent. But that's how the words developed in German after they'd been borrowed from Latin. The grammatical features in Latin and German differ, so such a borrowing cannot properly transfer grammatical features. `generalis` is a latin adjective used after the noun.

In German, an adjective can be used differently:

- attributive
- verbally
- in compounds similar to prefixes

These different usages changed over time, possibly differently.

Answer (score 2):

The apparent inconsequences when building adjectives from non-German loanwords can be easily understood with the examples you gave.

All adjectives ending with `-ell` are very likely loaned directly from French (*individuel, officiel, traditionnel, réel*) or were built to just sound French (*generell, speziell*) in the 18. Century when French was the hip language amongst Continental and German aristrocrats. Some of the adverbs already preexisted in their Latin or germanized Latin forms, and many of these still coexist happily next to each other.

Today we likely make our loanwords sound English rather than French (e.g. *Handy, Public Viewing, Provider*). It's just  a matter of fashion (and taste), really.

Comment: And maybe some hundred years in the future, someone will wonder what relation a Germanised "Proweider" has to a "Weide" ... :-)

Comment: Why use `Public Viewing` when there is a beautiful German word `Rudelglotzen` for it? ;-)