# -(i)al oder -(i)ell bei Suffigierung?

Tags: adjective-ending, suffix

Mein größter Fehler bei der Suffigierung deutscher [aus Nomen abgeleiteten Adjektiven](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/N-To-A/Suffig.html#Anchor-Tilgung-11481) ist die Wahl zwischen *-ial* oder *-iell*.
Z.B. heißt es *potenzial* oder *potenziell*? (Ich weiß nun welches richtig ist, aber erst nachdem ich schon ein Wörterbuch nachgeschlagen habe).

Gibt es eine Faustregel, um die richtige Endung zu erraten? Wenn ja, welche?

Comment: You might want to compare another question posted here: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12159/individuell-individual-and-generell-general-phenomena. It is not exactly your question but a related phenomenon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid not. In the worst case, there are both:

> ideal – optimal
>   ideell – non-material

or

> rational – rational
>   rationell – efficient

In other cases, the difference is less pronounced or exists only in connotation, e.g. *provinzial* vs *provinziell* (only the latter is used to describe provincial *Kleingeist*).

I guess the only safe bet is if one variant is taken by the noun itself (or another), e.g. *Potential* or *General*.