# »reell« vs. »real«

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen unterschied zwischen *reell* und *real?* Wann verwendet man was?

- > Die *reellen* Zahlen
- > Er hatte keine *reelle* Chance.

---

- > Ihr Traum war nicht *real.*
- > Die *Real*löhne sind in den vergangenen Jahren kaum gestiegen.

Die [einzige Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12159/individuell-individual-and-generell-general-phenomena/12160#12160), die ich hierzu finden konnte, erklärt nicht wirklich, was der Unterschied ist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die "reellen Zahlen" sind ein Fachausdruck, im Englischen heissen sie *real numbers*
Das "real" in Real-Löhne hat auch eine spezielle Bedeutung: unter Berückssichtigung der Inflationsrate
Jetzt zum allgemeinen Teil:
**Real** bedeutet 'wirklich' - der Traum ist imaginär. Es gibt nur Ja oder Nein.
 **Reell** entspricht 'realistisch' (edit: oder 'plausibel') - seine Chance war nicht Null, aber niemand hätte darauf gewettet. Hier sind Ausnahmen denkbar.

Comment: aber bedeutet 'realistisch' nicht auch 'wirklich'?

Comment: Ich kenne "reell" nur im Zusammenhang mit Zahlen, als Gegenteil von diskret. "reelle Chance" klingt imho falsch verwendet, muss "reale Chance" heißen.

Comment: @rexkogitans der Duden ist anderer Meinung: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/reell

Comment: @BobbyJ Das ist, weshalb ich vorsichtig "imho" schrieb. Mir sind diese Verwendungen nicht geläufig (regional?)

Comment: @PhilippStephan: die Bedeutungen überlappen natürlich. 'wirklich' ist ohne Zweifel, 'realistisch' lässt eine Unchärfe (Ausnahme) zu.

Comment: @PhilippStephan Man wird manchmal 'realistisch' durch 'wirklich' ersetzen können, aber grundsätzlich bedeuten die zwei nicht dasselbe: "Ich trinke wirklich keinen Alkohol" != "Ich trinke realistisch keinen Alkohol", "Man muss realistisch sein" != "Man muss wirklich sein"

Comment: @rexkogitans mir ist der Ausdruck *reell* in der Bedeutung *reelle Chance* durchaus geläufig. Aber wenn Du ihn vermeiden willst, solltest Du ihn eher durch *realistisch* als durch *real* ersetzen.

Answer (score 2):

"Reell" und "real" können in der Tat exakt dieselbe Bedeutung haben:
"Es wirkt so reell" = "es wirkt so real" = "es wirkt so realistisch" = "es wirkt so wirklich."
Auch in der Mathematik wird es synonym verwendet: 
Der "Realteil" einer imaginären Zahl = der "reelle Teil" einer imaginären Zahl.

Neben der gleichen Bedeutung "real" und "wirklich" hat reell eine weitere, davon unabhängige Bedeutung, nämlich "fair":
"Ein faires Angebot" = "ein reelles Angebot" und das ist womöglich was ganz anderes als ein "reales Angebot".