# Does "real" have a consistent connotation as a prefix to nouns?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, usage, difference

Calling one particular kind of (or view on) politics *Realpolitik* is understandable if the term's coiner considered it uniquely realistic, but "real politics" would not in English be a term with any clear or obvious connotation as to what kind of politics is "real".

The appearance of *Real* in *Realschule* is even more confusing. It immediately invites the question, what is more "real" about such a school than *Hauptschule* or *Gesamtschule*? (I've read various translations of the adjectives for these other school types, such as lowest or major vs overall or total.)

So here's my question: does German tend to use *real*, in general or at least at the beginning of nouns, in a non-literal manner applicable to both these examples? (For example, is it analogous to "real America", where "real" implies something typical and salt-of-the-Earth? Or perhaps to "get real", which implores a focus on the feasible?) Or are the connotations in these two examples dissimilar, or coincidentally similar but far from universal?

Comment: Feel free to edit the tags on this question, especially to remove inappropriate ones. I erred on the side of using a larger number of similar tags, as opposed to only tags I'm absolutely certain are relevant.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you see as the "literal" meaning of "real" - Its literal meaning is really [sic] "connected to things" (derived from Latin "res", or later "realis"). You seem to assume a different meaning.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/76326/so-whats-a-realencyclopadie

Comment: @tofro The _literal_ meaning of a "real school" in English would be a nonimaginary school. That obviously isn't what German _Realschule_ means, so the questioner was asking which of the myriad nonliteral senses was intended. (His initial guess was that it meant _nonfake_ or _unsophisticated_.) Your answer below is solid, though, so it looks like you figured that out.

Comment: Also related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/51989/reell-vs-real?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

German tends to use the *real-* prefix in its literal Latin meaning: "connected to things", or later Latin, *realis* - tangible, or rather as the opposite of *concept*, *theory*, or anything non-tangible or non-feasible.

That obviously offers a very wide area of possibilities to apply "real".

The term "Realschule" was originally developed to distinuish this form of schooling from a conceptual, academic, and more theoretical education offered in the *Gymnasium* as more down-to-earth ("connected to real things", rather than concepts). (Today, the term might have diffused into meaning "middle school education")

*Realpolitik* is thus the down-to-earth application of political concepts and theories to real-world problems.

I tend to think English doesn't use *real* in a very different way - your examples show pretty much the same bandwidth.

Comment: I gather the actual German cognate of "real" is "reell", and *real-* is a Latin prefix that happens to have a closer spelling to the English word.

Comment: @RDBury "real" (which is a proper adjective, not only a prefix) and "reell" actually mean pretty different things (with "reell" having a much narrower meaning)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know *real* was also an adjective. The English "real" is normally translated as *echt* or *wirklich*, while German *real* and *reell* seem more restricted to specialized and technical meanings, e.g  *Reelle Zahl*. According to Wiktionary, English "real" and German *reell* are from Old French, while German *real* comes directly from Latin.

Comment: It doesn't fit all the contexts where German _real_ does. It leads to the confusion here and in my questions just now. I think _real-world_ as an adjective (or _practical_ like the writer below suggests) probably _does_ capture the flavor of what you're talking about, though.

Answer (score 4):

Real(ism) is the antonym of Ideal(ism) - Idealism not on todays sense of, basically, do-gooderism, but as the notion that the world is made of, and influenced by, ideas, i.e. thoughts and reasons.

A "Gymnasium" (not to be confused with the English "Gymnasium", although it's the same greek word. A German "Gymnasium" is a secondary school) would usually follow the humanist idea of "Perfektibilität", the idea that you can achieve virtue of character by way of education - which due to some fascination with old Greece meant mostly languages and rhetoric (the concept of virtue was based on the greek notion of [arete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arete)). That's basically an "idealist" idea.

A Realschule, in contrast, would teach you e.g. how to manage your salary, how to grow a garden and what herb goes well with the chicken. This was intended to be "real" not so much in the salt-of-the-earth sense, but quite literally as in that these were things you could touch with your hands (the concept also proved to be a winner, as Prussia soon allowed Realschule graduates in public service, maybe in deference to the fact that knowing how to manage a garden is sometimes more useful to the public enterprise than possessing *arete*).

Realpolitik follows basically the same pattern - the idea originally was that it is virtuous to have enlighted goals, but that the quickest way to bring them about is by using a big stick (although in some quarters the meaning has changed today to thinking that you should not have high-minded goals at all and just have the stick).

The oppositon of Idealism and Realism/Materialism was for quite some time the driving force behind most of German philosophy. Of course, these days philosophers do not have much clout in Germany, so this is not something that is hugely in our mind when we use the prefix "real" - it often simply means "practical", possibly at the expense of some noble intentions, or else that a seemingly good thing falls shorts of some actual goal (i.e. "Reallohnverlust", the fact that people can afford less even with nominally higher wages).