# So what's a "Realencyclopädie"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, etymology, german-to-english, history

Given the importance of Pauly's work ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realencyclop%C3%A4die_der_classischen_Altertumswissenschaft), [Wikisource](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Paulys_Realencyclop%C3%A4die_der_classischen_Altertumswissenschaft)), I assume it wasn't written in gibberish by a madman. That said, what secondary or tertiary sense does the German *real* or *Real* have that makes the titles *Real-Encyclopädie der classischen Alterthumswissenschaft in alphabetischer Ordnung* and *Realencyclopädie der classischen Altertumswissenschaft* make any sense at all?

The only Wikis that seem to provide a gloss are Spanish and Russian, which both use cognates. Spanish [*real*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/real#Spanish) could obviously mean *royal*, which would make sense. The [Russian translation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9#Russian) and Wiktionary's treatment of German [*real*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/real#German) and [*Real*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Real#German) don't seem to allow that possibility, though. Cursory googling turns up a [few](https://books.google.fr/books?id=0-IS7aET9GUC&pg=PP9) [other](https://books.google.fr/books?id=alUHmItQb8IC&pg=PP5) books with similar titles, so it's not just Pauly's eccentricity.

So what's going on? Is it just an archaic way of saying "scientific dictionary"? or what would a decent modern English gloss of these titles be, distinguishing the intended sense of a "real encyclopedia" against whatever it considers its inverse to be?

Comment: Bonus points if you can point out why in German it might make sense to qualify _Altertumswissenschaft_ with _classischen_, which creates the redundant "Classical Classical Studies" in literal English translation.

Comment: I suppose (thus just a comment, not an answer) that the title relates to the intended use/audience of the "Ur-Pauly" (!) at school, not primarily in an academic environment - similar to "Realschule".

Comment: @tohuwawohu Not saying you're wrong but, if the whole idea of a [realschool](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/real_school) was that they _weren't_ focused on Latin and classical studies, the title then becomes _The Self-Contradictory Encyclopedia of Classical Classical Studies_? or what additional context is still missing? Maybe something like _Real-World Encyclopedia_ involving more archaeological and epigraphic work as opposed to _only_ looking at the surviving texts on their own?

Comment: On the bonus points, antiquity refers to anything in the distant past, but Classical antiquity refers to the cultures of Ancient Greece, Rome, and related areas. So Chinese antiquity would not be considered "Classical". Meanwhile Classical does not refer to age but to a certain aesthetic considered to be a characteristic of Ancient Greece, Rome, etc.

Comment: It's mostly guesswork, so just a comment, but there's a distinction between "formale Bildung" and "reale Bildung". Sometimes, the distinction is between "humanistische Bildung" and "reale Bildung". The [Wikipedia article on 'Realschule'](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realschule) explains that "reale Bildung" referred to education about "real things", education that was considered "useful". I'd reckon that an "Realenzyklopädie" followed similar principles, to teach only what was considered "necessary". It's beyond my expertise to dive deeper into this, but maybe somebody can continue from here.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [»reell« vs. »real«](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/51989/43989)

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/67227/does-real-have-a-consistent-connotation-as-a-prefix-to-nouns

Comment: @RDBury At least within English, "classical" is similarly ambiguous (although here obviously focused on Greece and Rome) but "antiquity" without qualifiers _always_ refers to the ancient Mediterranean in the classical period. In German, you'd honestly expect a treatment of _Altertumswissenschaft_ to cover India, China, and possibly prehistory as well without further qualification? If so, fair enough... but I do have doubts, especially in the context of 19th century universities and academic writing.

Comment: @CarstenS That's _exactly_ on point and probably the crux of the issue. The suggestion there is (where "real" would feel weird in English) to use "practical" instead. "Real-world" would also fit. I'm still a little curious what made this book more practical than similar works on the topic but that's probably the core of the answer. If you wanna type up some version of that into an answer, I'd upvote it and check it off. Further info about the _RE_ itself could be added down the road if you're unsure.

Comment: @lly Say hello to the [Reallexikon der Germanischen Altertumskunde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanische_Altertumskunde_Online) ;-) (Truth be told, it is newer and its title may be inspired by the Pauly.)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Actually, a real dictionary might make sense compared to the English _Dictionary of Imaginary Places_, _The Meaning of Liff_, and similar compendia of nonsense. Similarly, German antiquity makes sense in a way that "classical antiquity" somewhat doesn't in English (unless you're saying you're focused on the height of Athens and Rome versus their archaic or late variants). In any case, I think we have this cracked now. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I concur with the other answers in that *real* (from latin *res*, via *realis*; *sachlich*) means dealing with more than the meaning of words, instead presenting knowledge in a summary format. *Realwörterbuch* was actually used as a synonym for *Enzyklopädie*; see for instance [Deutsche Encyclopädie oder Allgemeines Real-Wörterbuch aller Künste und Wissenschaften](https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/en/details/bsb10326000).

*Meyers Konversationslexikon* has an article [Encyklopädie](https://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=105024) which contains the following statement.

> Ihren Vorläufer hatte die E. in lexikalischer Form (Realencyklopädie) bereits in dem "Lexikon" betitelten Realwörterbuch des Suidas (10.-11. Jahrh.) gehabt; eine weitere Pflege erfuhr sie aber erst im 17. Jahrh.

From this I conclude, in contrast to the other answers, that *Realenzyklopädie* was actually not pleonastic for a certain period of time: it was an encyclopaedia written in the form of a dictionary or lexicon, i.e. with knowledge presented in articles that are arranged alphabetically. Note that the full title of Pauly's work is [Real-Encyclopädie der classischen Alterthumswissenschaft in alphabetischer Ordnung](https://dewiki.de/b/5cea).

Examples of encylopaedias that did not have the format of a lexicon are [Enzyklopädie der philosophischen Wissenschaften im Grundrisse](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Hegel,+Georg+Wilhelm+Friedrich/Enzyklop%C3%A4die+der+philosophischen+Wissenschaften+im+Grundrisse) and [Allgemeine illustrierte Encyklopädie der Musikgeschichte](https://archive.org/details/allgemeineillust01ritt/page/n5/mode/2up).

Answer (score 10):

Spanish *real* ("royal") stems from Spanish *rey*, which roots in latin *rex* ("king"). The *Real*-Prefix in your word stems from latin *res* ("thing"), which is, by the way, also the root of the word *republic*. A *Realwörterbuch* or *Real-Encyclopädie* is an "encyclopedia of things", as opposed to a *Wörterbuch* which is simply a dictionary, or "an encyclopedia of terms". (The English word *real* and the German word *real* also root in Latin *res* through the Latin adjective *realis* "of things".)

Differentiating between things and notions is an import distinction in history of thought. When the hammer was invented is a totally different question from when the word *hammer* was invented. You might find the latter in a dictionary, the former in an encyclopedia.

While the term *Realwörterbuch* fell out of fashion, the same prefix is still used in the term *Realschule*, referring to a school where the focus is on practical rather than on academic education (you learn "things" there, less "ideas" or "theories").

Same as its English counterpart *encyclopedia*, the German word *Enzyklopädie* used to have a broader meaning, referring to a "collection of knowledge"; the distinction between encyclopedia and dictionary which is common today, is of a younger age. That is why the specification of an "encyclopedia of things" might have made sense at the time the book was written.

Answer (score 6):

It's another name for a so called [Realwörterbuch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realw%C3%B6rterbuch), or by modern laymen terms a *Lexikon*. In English this would be an encyclopedia.

The contrasting term is *Sprachwörterbuch*. Those explain the word rather than the things described by that word. The layman term for those is *Wörterbuch*. In English this would be a dictionary.

And yeah, *Realencyclopädie* sounds like a pleonasm in hindsight.

Comment: bin geneigt diese wie die anderen Antworten abzuwählen, weil es einfach nur ein Link auf eine zweifelhafte Quelle ohne Quellenkritik ist. Aber immerhin: ein Link und eine Aussage, wenn auch eine falsche.

Answer (score -2):

*Realia* means “things”. This contrasts with dictionaries and lexica concerned with other matters. The form simply follows function. “Scientific” or better *real* in the sense of "true" is a legitimate interpretation.

---

*Realia* heißen "Sachen". Der Titel *Reallexikon* stammt in diesem Sinne vermutlich von *res* ~ *rem* "Sache".

Die Abgrenzung zu spanish *real* "royal", ferner im Zusammenhang stehend bspw. *Recht*, ist nicht leicht, da die Zusammenhänge zum Teil unbekannt gewesen, zum Teil falsch hergestellt sein könnten. Siehe nur englisch *realestate* zu *res*, ursprünglich im Sinne von Mobiliar, beweglichen Sachen, später Immobilien, der Hof mit dazu gehörenden Sachen, und demgegenüber deutsch *Regal* ... was ungefähr den Umfang eines anständigen Lexikons beschreibt.

Für eine genauere Betrachtung ist die deutsche Etymologie wahrscheiich nicht verantwortlich. Es ist völlig offensichtlich, dass *real* ungefähr als wahr- oder richtigkeit verstanden worden sein wird. S.a. *Rechtschreibung* wie *ortho-graphie*, aber im Sinne von *regulus* (Regulator, König) vergleichbar noch *the Queen's English*, “as she is spoke”, jedoch auch *real* wie *Sprachrealität* im Sinne beschreibender Grammatik. Für *royal* spricht außerdem verallgemeinerung des Titels für Größenamgaben oder sonstige Überlegenheit, so *Royal-TS, T-Rex, king-penguin, Königshappen, Frank-Reich*, zumal Forschungsvorhaben sehr oft auf staatliche Förderung hin angewiesen sind. Siehe dazu insbesondere  *regesta imperii*:

> “Die REGESTA IMPERII verzeichnen sämtliche urkundlich und historiographisch belegten Aktivitäten der römisch-deutschen Könige und Kaiser”